# Footer overlapping the content when browser window is shrunk

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to avoid the overlapping of the div's when the browser window is shrinked vertically in the following piece of code:

`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <style>
            #box {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
            }
            #top {
                background-color: red;
                height: 560px;
                width: 400px;
            }
            #bottom {
                background-color: green;
                height: 100px;
                width: 400px;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0
            }
        </style>
        <div id="box">
          <div id="top">
          </div>
          <div id="bottom">
          </div>
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

`

Why are the div's getting overlapped. is there a way that this overlapping can be avoided and having the same initial structure? The bottom div acts as a footer in the real scenario. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to ready sticky footer using Flexbox. The blog talks sticky footer, but you apply same to your component. https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/#article-header-id-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `min-height` on the `box`, remove absolute positioning from the `bottom` and both `div`'s heights will be kept.

When the `margin-top: auto` is set on a flex column item, it will push it to the bottom of is parent, which you can see on bigger screens.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;                  /*  IE bug fix  */
}

#box {
  flex-grow: 1;                   /*  fill body's width  */

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#top {
  background-color: red;
  height: 560px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#bottom {
  margin-top: auto;               /*  push it to the bottom on big screen  */
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="top">
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If they at some point they need to shrink, with this sample the red `div` does, where the height is fixed to full viewport.

It works like that, that the green is given `flex-shrink: 0`, which prevent it from shrink and keep its set height.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#top {
  background-color: red;
  height: 560px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#bottom {
  margin-top: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="top">
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `position: relative;` to parent, in this case to `body` element, it will solve the issue. When the parent's position is `relative`, and the child's position is `absolute`, the child will respect parent and will be positioned relatively to the parent:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

#box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
#top {
    background-color: red;
    height: 560px;
    width: 400px;
}
#bottom {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="top">
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```